# VBA StrComp - Compare values with exceptions

Tags: excel, vba

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMwDc.png)I have today's data in column D which I want to compare with yesterday's data in column F, row wise.

Below is the code I'm using to compare and highlight duplicates.

**A) Highlighting blank cells which I don't want.
B) I want to handle some exceptions like I don't wish to highlight $0.00 or specific text "No Data"**

```
Sub CompareAndHighlight()

Dim Myrng1 As Range, Myrng2 As Range, i As Long, j As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For i = 3 To Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set Myrng1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & i)
    For j = 3 To Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set Myrng2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F" & j)
        If StrComp(Trim(Myrng1.Text), Trim(Myrng2.Text), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        'If Myrng1.Value = Myrng2.Value Then
        Myrng1.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        End If
        Set Myrng2 = Nothing
    Next j
    Set Myrng1 = Nothing
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

[Data giving random errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFimp.png) on running macros multiple times after clearing highlighted colors.

Comment: Could you write more specifically what it is you'd like to accomplish? It seems that, based on what I'm seeing / understanding, that this could be fairly easily done via conditional formatting without any need for VBA if that would work for you.

Comment: Sorry @JohnBustos I only saw your comment now.

Answer (score 0):

Use the conditional formatting function.

```
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
Selection.FormatConditions(1).DupeUnique = xlDuplicate
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
    .Color = -16383844
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 13551615
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
```

Then after this create one loop that goes through your range and turns the colour of the cell to no colour where your conditions are met, alternatively you could just filter the data to exclude your cases, such as "No Data", and copy and paste the results into a new column. In fact you do not really need vba for this.

Answer (score 0):

sticking with VBA you could try the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CompareAndHighlight()
    Dim refRng As Range, cell As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set refRng = .Range("F3", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants)
        For Each cell In .Range("D3", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants)
            If cell.value <> 0 And cell.value <> "No Data" Then
                If refRng.Find(what:=cell.value, LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False) Is Nothing Then cell.Interior.color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
            End If
        Next cell
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Is working when I used - If refRng.Find(what:=cell.value, LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False) Is Nothing Then cell.Interior.color = RGB(255, 255, 0)   [Insted of If Not]

Comment: Thank you user3598756, however I am still facing one issue, the macro is highlighting non-duplicate items randomly.

Comment: Are your data coming from formulas or are they constant values?

Comment: All are constant values, Importing data from text to excel, no formulas. I tried checking the code by adding dummy values (Numbers, 0, No Data, Null) in column D and F.

Comment: Update your question with data that give you that random behavior

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: my code works with your data, being them formatted as text or currency: it highlights in column D either duplicates (using `If Not refRng.Find(...)`) or unique values (using `If refRng.Find(...)`. As per your question it begins scanning data from row `3`. But all what above is also the behavior I can see as per your updated image: so what are the random errors you're talking about? May be you're not returning all cells background color to "none" before every macro execution.

Comment: @sumit: did you get through t?

Comment: for some weird reason its not giving me the desired result.  Everytime I run the macro after making background color to "none" (by selecting column D and choosing No Fill) - 1) - It's highlighting blank cells in column D. 2) - Its highlighting non-duplicate values as well.  My column D has about 300 values few are blanks, $0.00, No Data, amounts.

Comment: again, my code works with data you gave some one month before. may be you may post new data you're having problems with

Comment: I tried adding new data to this post, see if you can get some idea and would like to thank you for pitching in.